# Does the command SET STATISTICS...ON turn statistics information on for all queries running throughout the server or just the current connection?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, statistics

In regards to `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` and `SET STATISTICS IO ON` I noticed in the remarks of the Microsoft doc, it says the following:

> When STATISTICS IO is ON, statistical information is displayed, and
>   when OFF, the information isn't displayed.
>
> After this option is set ON, all Transact-SQL statements return the
>   statistical information until the option is set to OFF.

Does that mean all Transact-SQL statements that execute in the current connection, or across the whole server?
When I tested it myself, it seemed to be only within the scope of my connection.

Comment: The Transact-SQL programming language provides several SET statements that change the **current session** handling of specific information. [SET Statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to the question can be found higher up the document tree:

[image]

[SET statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The Transact-SQL programming language provides several SET statements
>   that change the current session handling of specific information. The
>   SET statements are grouped into the categories shown in the following
>   table.

Which explains that all these set statements are applied to the current session.

With the category for `SET STATISTICS IO,TIME ON;` being statistics statements

[image]

Comment: So it's no big deal then in an ad-hoc query session if I left SET STATISTICS...ON for a while, since as long as I'm not actively running any queries in that session, nothing should be affected by it outside of my session?

Comment: @J.D. That is correct :)

Answer (score 3):

This relates to "all Transact-SQL statements that execute in the current connection"
"only within the scope of my connection"

NOT across the whole server

Comment: I would stick to current session than connection.